# DBeaver file encoding (cp1250 - Windows-1250) - change default encoding?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, dbeaver, cp1250

I have a problem setting encoding in DBeaver, specifically
SQL file encoding (not db encoding!)
to cp1250 (Windows-1250)

No problem to set such encoding for new files/scripts - right click on Scripts folder (or the whole project folder, from which scripts are inheriting): 
Properties / Resources / Text file encoding.

The problem is opening existing scripts from text files (SQL Editor / Load script). These are loaded in UTF-8, which is shown as deafult encoding. No easy way to change the encoding after opening...

Does anyone know how to change default encoding for DBeaver (or for opened files)? 
I cannot find the answer anywhere...

Answer (score 60):

see capture file below for a detailed explanation.
Hope this helps (if still relevant)...

[image: Visual Explanation]

Comment: I set UTF-8, but still in the answer set I see only empty strings for all UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Nice shout. It seem to cache things too btw. I found I altered the schema collation from latin to utf8.. It wasn't until I exited and re-entered DBeaver that data grid took and displayed unusual characters such as Cédric or Dervişoğlu correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Korean(한글) users who wish to set encoding to UTF-8, follow steps marked on the below figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved removing the UTF encoding from the driver settings.

Right click on Data Base > Edit Connection F4 > click on button ‘Edit Driver Settings’ > click on Tab ‘Driver Properties’ > Right click on ‘encoding UTF8’ > Remove Property> OK>

click on Tab ‘Driver Properties’ > Right click on ‘encoding UTF8’ > Remove Property> OK